# How can I boot to Windows on my Mac?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro that I installed Windows 8 on via Boot Camp. I've managed to boot to it, before, but since then I've made two new partitions on the disk, and I'm afraid it's messed things up since I can't boot to Windows anymore.

Now when I select which partition to boot to, I can only see my Mac OSX, A backup partition, and the Recovery partition. The Windows partition does appear in Disk Utility though.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to System Preferences...

There in the System row go to Statup Disk

And select the Windows partition.

Restart...

---

During Startup try holding the <kbd>option</kbd> key. You should be able to select the partition you will boot from.